# Refresh page button using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to create a button in visual studio that refreshes the entire browser page. Currently, I have a web part that is deployed onto sharepoint 2010. I would like to add a button to refreshes the page dynamically so that my web part content changes. It is because, my web part has a random code which changes information every 10 seconds, but to view the changes the page has to be refreshed constantly. I want to just add a button to my web part to hit refresh. Is it possible?

Comment: Why add a button to your web page when there's a perfectly good one in every browser?

Comment: you could refresh just the code using ajax

Comment: if you want to auto refresh try AJAX-enabled Web Part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways, but all use JavaScript on the button. Here's my favourite:

```
<input type=button value="Refresh" onClick="history.go()">
```

The "type=button" prevents the button from causing a postback. `onclick="history.go()` says to go to the last item in the history list, i.e. the current page.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..... If you want to refresh the page in button click , **you can set this into button click....**

```
 <html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);">
<p>This page will refresh every 5 seconds. This is because we're using the 'onload' event to call our function. We are passing in the value '5000', which equals 5 seconds.</p>
<p>But hey, try not to annoy your users too much with unnecessary page refreshes every few seconds!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one
input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()